# .NET TableLayoutPanel: Last Column Width 'Too Wide'

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, tablelayoutpanel

Please let me know if there is a better, more 'conventional,' solution to this:

According to Microsoft, TableLayoutPanel column widths are determined as follows:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.columnstyles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

- Columns with ColumnStyle set to Absolute are considered first, and their fixed widths are allocated.
- Columns with ColumnStyle set to AutoSize are sized to their contents.
- Remaining space is divided among columns with ColumnStyle set to Percent.

I am unconvinced, particularly about the third point.  In recent (greuling) experimentation, I experienced the following:

[Properties:  TableLayoutPanel]

AutoScroll = False (tried True)

AutoSize = False (tried True)

ALL ColumnStyle SizeType properties set to "Percent" (tried every other concievable combination)

In this case, as the TableLayoutPanel is resized, the right-most column is always assigned the remainder of the equation:

W / Ncolumns = ColumnWidth

Where:

W = Width of TableLayoutPanel

Ncolumns = number of columns

The right-most column ends up being wider than the rest of the columns in all testing.  This is true for .NET 2.0 and .NET 4.0 controls.

In research, I discoverd some ad-hock solutions such as adding a non-used column to the right of the rest, and assigning it a SizeType = Absolute, Size = 0 property.  This was also ineffective during resizing, in my testing.  Also, if that is somehow the 'solution', I will be mucho surprised.

So, in the absence of an Internet-found solution that worked in my testing, and in light of the fact that MS might consider this a 'feature'
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fea60d24-70d2-4cd8-91f8-57ae23ac9972/table-layout-panel-column-size-problem?forum=vbgeneral
I decided to write my own inheriting Class.

I admit that the code below is not refined / could be more efficient / needs more cowbell.  I'm okay with that, because in the screenshots below it, I get what I was looking for:  A TableLayoutPanel that ACTUALLY keeps all of its contained controls as close to evenly-sized as possible.  The 'remainder' error is distributed over the contained controls.

```
Public Class MyOwnTableLayoutPanel
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel

    Public Shadows Sub OnResize() Handles Me.Resize
        Dim w As Double = Me.Width / Me.ColumnStyles.Count
        '// get 'normal' width (sans-remainder distribution)
        w = Math.Truncate(w)
        Dim remainder As Integer = Me.Width Mod Me.ColumnStyles.Count
        Dim pointer As Integer = 1
        '// distribute the 'remainder' across some of the controls;
        '   should result, usually, in not more than one pixel deviation from 'normal'
        For i As Integer = 0 To Me.ColumnStyles.Count - 1
            Me.ColumnStyles(i).SizeType = SizeType.Absolute
            pointer += 1
            If Not pointer > remainder Then
                Me.ColumnStyles(i).Width = w + 1
            Else
                Me.ColumnStyles(i).Width = w
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

[Screenshot 0]

Seen here, the top TableLayoutPanel is my derived Class.  The lower is the original MS Class.  Note that the original already has an error in the width of the right-most column.

[image]

[Screenshot 1]

'Button38' (sorry, lazy) causes both TableLayoutPanel controls to be widened by 5 pixels.  Note the error in the original.

[image]

[Screenshot 2]

Further widening also illustrates the error.  Note that the derived Class maintains a closer normalization of the button widths.

[image]

Again, this is just my code-around 'solution' for what I cannot figure out otherwise.  To the best of my knowledge, the TableLayoutPanel, as published by Microsoft, does not actually distribute the 'remainder' of width division across its columns.  I'd be happy to see working code of it doing so (pretend I'm an idiot and post all the code, as if I know nothing).

Comment: [Self-answering is okay on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), but please modify your post to the proper question/answer format.  Otherwise it may be deleted.

Comment: I'm not exactly self-answering.  I'm looking for whether or not my solution is good, and/or a more 'conventional' alternative.  Elsewise....I'm unaware of the "proper" format.

Comment: Also, I have modified the opening to state a request.